# What is the difference between terminate_instances() and terminate() in boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to delete the instance using `boto3` According to the documentation, there are two methods for deleting the instance using boto3.

[terminate()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=terminate_instances#EC2.ServiceResource.terminate)
[terminate_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=terminate_instances#EC2.Client.terminate_instances)

What is the difference between these two methods and which one should I use for deleting the instance?

Using terminate_instances() throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'terminate_instances'
```

```py
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

Instances = ec2.terminate_instances(InstanceIds=['i-xxxxxxxx'])
print(Instances)
```

What is the correct way to delete the instance using boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is simply the caller of the function.

The `terminate` function is performed on a collection of instances you have already retrieved.

The `terminate_instances` function is performed from the client, and requires you to specify the filter of which instances you need to terminate.